# Distinguish message which receive from socket.getInputStream()

Tags: android, ios, sockets

I get bit problem, The problem is as follows:

At server socket, server receive data type as byte array:

```
this.receiveStream = new DataInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());
byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
while (this.receiveStream.read(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.length) > -1) {
String dataReceive = new String(receiveBuffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).trim();
}
```

If client send text message in one thread then server run well, but if client run >=2 thread concurrent to send text message then at server, the message were mixed, it mean clientThead1 send "ABC", clientThead2 send "XYZ" => server receive "AXBC" OR "AXYZ",... => It is not expected message.
**How to solve this problem???**

P/S: I have tested with server receive message as text, it work well:

```
while (true) {
String dataReceive = this.receiveStream.readUTF().trim();
}
```

But i can not use it, because server serve muti platform client, so i want to server use byte array to receive data

Thanks all,

**UPDATE:**
I can not post full code because it is very long character

**This is link all code Client + Server**:https://www.mediafire.com/folder/j4d041uqfowt6/SocketApp

Answer (score 0):

Do you use TCP or UDP? It is important, the sockets do not hide the difference.

For TCP,
the client threads must not reuse the same connection.

Each client thread must open its own connection, as if it were applications on different devices.

The server must start a new thread each time it listening socket receives a job. That thread will use its own connection; threads servicing different clients are independent as if it were applications on different devices.

I think you see the logic: one client thread <--> one service thread.

(I think you know that a listening socket does not receive data, it creates a data socket).

For UDP, on the server side you have to distinguish the clients yourself.
It would not be possible if you were sending single bytes, but packets are not single bytes, UDP packets include auxiliary information. You have the sender's IP and port, so you can distinguish the clients if they are not two threads using the same port on the same IP.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I use TCP Socket, 

This problem here:
In client, function sendKeepAlive() which will send message period to check connect with server. Therefore when client send message then at server message mixed, It is not expected message.

Please check update question and help me

Comment: It is absolutely wrong to have `gNewClientSocket`. You can have a global variable only if you have _exactly one_ client socket. In addition I see `private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ProcessingClient> onlineClients` inside `ProcessingClient`. It means that you tried different things to get your code working and did not succeed, and left the things as they happened to be.  Just rewrite everything.

Comment: This is server can serve muilti concurrent client connect, so i can not use global variable for one client.
All source code, clients can send and receive message together. It haapend error when function sendKeepAlive() and user send message concurrent

Comment: The problem may happen only if sendKeepAlive() and sendUserMessage() are run from different threads. In the worst case, you can do `synchronized(someLock) {` _`do-actual-sending`_ `}` in both threads

Comment: Thanks, In my code, function sendDataToServer(), i have locked with synchronized (sendStream){} but it is same problem...anything ideal?

Answer (score 0):

Use a child thread to read data from socket and main thread to accept request and hand over to child..

**Server**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server extends Thread {

    public Server(String ip, int port) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ser = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Listening....");
            while (true) {
                Socket soc = ser.accept();
                new Child(soc).start();
                System.out.println("Child Started...");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    private class Child extends Thread {

        Socket cSoc;

        public Child(Socket soc) {
            this.cSoc = soc;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String data = "";
                InputStream in = cSoc.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                int ch = 0, cnt = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Message Length = " + length);
                while ((ch = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    data += new String(buffer);
                    cnt += ch;
                    if (cnt >= length) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Message = " + data);
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server("localhost", 1234).start();
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
            OutputStream o = s.getOutputStream();
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(o);
            String data = "your data";
            ps.println(data.length());
            Thread.sleep(100);
            o.write(data.getBytes());
            ps.close();
            o.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

It's just a sample implementation you can wrap the concept.

Comment: Thanks for your response,Yes, my system is same with you,

This problem here:
In client, function sendKeepAlive() which will send message period to check connect with server. Therefore when client send message then at server message mixed, It is not expected message.

Please check update question and help me